# Rotating dust in Gödel universe

Tags: general-relativity

I have a question regarding the Gödel metric. Supposedly the Gödel universe is filled with rotating pressure-less dust. 
However, checking different sources, it seems like Einstein's field equations are satisfied in this case for a perfect fluid without pressure and 4-velocity $u^{\mu}=\left(1,0,0,0\right)$ , placing some restrictions on the cosmological constant and the matter density.
Since that 4-velocity represents a dust distribution that is at rest everywhere, I don't understand why it is said to be rotating. I guess it must be something very obvious but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coordinate velocities in GR are generally meaningless. They have no special physical interpretation. To find out whether a particular spacetime has rotation, you need to consider some coordinate-independent criterion. [WP has this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_metric#Rigid_rotation):

> The frame fields given above are both *inertial*, $\nabla_{\vec{e}_0} \vec{e}_0 = 0$, but the *vorticity vector* of the timelike geodesic congruence defined by the timelike unit vectors is 
>   $$-\omega \vec{e}_2$$
>   This means that the world lines of nearby dust particles are twisting about one another. Furthermore, the *shear tensor* of the congruence $\vec{e}_0$ *vanishes*, so the dust particles exhibit *rigid rotation*.